# Print report button missing on embedded Report Viewer Web Part

Tags: 2010, web-part, reporting-services, reports

The print button is missing on my report viewer web part. When I try to configure the web part in Site Settings -> Galleries -> Web Parts (ReportViewer.dwp) to see if I can somehow re-enable showing that button in the web part default configuration, it says "This web part has not been configured correctly. Please contact the document owner.".

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this further.

Comment: which browser you are using?

Comment: what about the other browsers than IE ? will it work on the other browsers? what are all the other workarounds or possibilities to get this option available on other browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being that I was using Internet Explorer 11 and the print button does not show up unless I turn on compatibility mode (in the Internet Explorer settings).